# What is the importance of the spectral theorem?

Tags: linear-algebra, motivation, big-picture

I know that the spectral theorem tells us that in the case of a real inner product space, an operator is self adjoint if and only if there is an orthonormal basis with only eigenvectors of that operator and that in the case of a complex inner product space, an operator is normal if and only if there is an orthonormal basis with only eigenvectors.

However, I am unable to see what is so important about this. I know that this means I can diagonalize the matrix but I don't know what is so good about diagonalizing a matrix. Also, why do we have to have an orthonormal basis? Why can it not be a standard basis?

Thank you!

Comment: A diagonalizable endomorphism $f$ on $V$ can be written as a “direct sum” so to speak of multiplications $f = \oplus_i (λ_i ·) \colon \bigoplus_i V_i → \bigoplus_i V_i$ where $V = \bigoplus V_i$ is a decomposition of $V$ into the eigenspaces $V_i$ of $f$ with respective eigenvalues $λ_i$. I know, this is no application and no real reason for why it should be important, but isn’t that nice? (Well, generally it’s a direct product, but in the finite dimensional case this is equivalent.)

Comment: I don't think this is enough for a full answer, but the spectral theorem implies that the adjacency matrix of a graph has an orthonormal basis. This, in turn, gives rise to all of (finite) spectral graph theory.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks to the spectral theorem you can easily compute the powers of a given diagonalizable matrix $A = P^{-1}D P$ (as @Gerry Myerson said), thanks to the relation
$$A^k = P^{-1}D^k P.$$
But you can also exploit the diagonalization to evaluate more complex matrix functions, e.g. the *matrix exponential*. Indeed you have 
$$e^A = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{A^k}{k!} = P^{-1}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{D^k}{k!} P = P^{-1}e^D P,$$
and for diagonal matrices $D = \text{diag}(d_1,\ldots,d_n)$ we have the simple relation 
$$e^D = \text{diag}(e^{d_1},\ldots,e^{d_n}).$$ 
This holds in general for any matrix function defined as a power series, indeed if you have $f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k x^k$, then 
$$f(A) = P^{-1} f(D) P,$$
where $f(D) = \text{diag}(f(d_1),\ldots,f(d_n)).$

[EDIT: notice that the matrix exponential is extremely important, because thanks to this tool you can e.g. solve linear differential systems of equations $\dot{\mathbf{x}}(t) = A(t) \mathbf{x}(t) + \mathbf{b}(t)$.]

Answer (score 11):

Write down a square matrix, $A$. Now, raise it to the power 100. Not so easy, is it? Well, it is if the matrix is diagonal. It's also easy if the matrix is diagonalizable; if $P^{-1}AP=D$ is diagonal, then $A^{100}=PD^{100}P^{-1}$. So, computing high powers of matrices is made easy by diagonalization.

And why would you want to compute high powers of a matrix? Well, many things are modelled by discrete linear dynamical systems, which is a fancy way of saying you have a sequence of vectors $v_0,v_1,v_2,\dots$ where you get each vector (after the first) by multiplying the previous vector by $A$. But then $v_k=A^kv_0$, and voila! there's your high power of a matrix.